# How to add previous parameter and the current parameter in a SSRS parameter

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

I have 3 parameters for my SSRS report.  My first parameter is for search the data that will be shows on.  The second parameter and the third parameter is for save the second parameter selected value. I already tried to use `Join` to join the previous selected value and current selected value, but on my third parameter it keep replacing with the new one. And the previous parameter will be disappear.

How can I add the previous and the current parameter like this function += on integer when we want to add the previous number and the current number in looping instead replacing it.

Comment: Can you post expected results with examples of all the parameters?

Comment: my expected result is like this, parameter 1 its for search , parameter 2 will shows the result of search its already work, and the third parameter will save the selected value from parameters 2, that still does'nt work. The third parameter always refershering so the previous parameters is dissapear

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like that for your 3 parameter:

```
= Join(Parameters!Parameter2.Value, Parameters!Parameter3.Value, ";")
```

But you have to handle **Null** values for parameter 3 and 2. Also I dont think it makes sense to save the paramter like this. For example what happens when the user selects value A, B, C for parameter 2 and afterwards he selects B, E. Now you have B twice.